# Multiple statements in a switch expression: C# 8

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, switch-expression

Switch expressions were introduced in C# 8. There's plenty of places in codebases, which may be rewritten in this new style.

For example, I have some code, which is used for parsing packets from a stream of bytes:

```cs
switch (command)
{
    case Command.C1:
        return new P1();
    case Command.C2:
        return new P2();
    default:
        stream.Position++;
        return null;
}
```

The problem is - it can't be converted to a switch expression like

```cs
return command switch
{
    Command.C1 => new P1(),
    Command.C3 => new P2(),
    _ => { stream.Position++; return null; }
};
```

The first thing that got in my mind was to use a `Func<>`, which compiles:

```cs
return command switch
{
    Command.C1 => new P1(),
    Command.C3 => new P2(),
    _ => new Func<AbstractPacket>(() => { stream.Position++; return null; })()
};
```

F# already allows code with multiple statements in each branch:

```ml
match command with
| Command.C1 -> Some(P1() :> AbstractPacket)
| Command.C2 -> Some(P2() :> AbstractPacket)
| _ ->
    stream.Position <- stream.Position + 1
    None
```

Now I'm stuck using switch-statements, but is there any option to write this as a switch-expression without any weird hacks?

Comment: Nitpick: "expression" doesn't have that many S's in it.

Comment: so suggest an edit?

Comment: Personally, I would convert to a `switch` statement in such cases. That said, C# LDM is discussing some options to allow statements inside `switch` expressions and possibly more generally ("expression blocks"). Here's the proposal we most recently reviewed: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3086

Comment: The switch expression **is not meant to** replace the switch statement. It serves a different purpose. It will not handle multiple statements, and it shouldn't, because you're just switching on a value to get the right **single** expression evaluated. So you're entirely right, getting the switch expression to handle multiple statements is a pain, in pretty much the same way as using a hammer to split a plank in two is.

Comment: My comment above aside, what are you actually asking about here? Do you have a usecase where you have to use a switch expression but must have statements? Or is this just an academic question, like "how can I subvert a switch expression to take the place of a switch statement"? Basically, which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I'm just refactoring code and searching for solution with best readability

Comment: @JL0PD it's expression, singular. You can't have multiple expressions in an `if` or assignment expression. David Conrad's comment is actually the answer

Comment: @JohnLord David Conrad's comment is actually the answer - an expression is *one* thing, not multiple. It can be one function call, or one logical expression or a composite of other expressions etc.

Comment: @JL0PD switch *expressions* aren't a new version of switch statements, or a way to make them prettier. They are a unique new construct. In fact, F# *doesn't allow multiple expressions* in each branch either - those are individual *functions*

Comment: @JL0PD you can use local functions to combine multiple statements into one function that can be used in any expression, including switch expressions

Comment: @JL0PD BTW the ternary operator, `?:` works the same way too. You can't put multiple statements there either.

Comment: As a C# dev, my expectation was that multi-line statements/side-effects would be supported. We do it all day with LINQ, where we can flexibly write Select(MethodName), Select( a => b), or Select( c => { Console.WriteLine("d"); return d; });

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your only supported choice is the func like you did. See [this article][1] for more information. His example:

```
var result = operation switch
{
"+" => ((Func<int>)(() => {
    Log("addition");
    return a + b;
}))(),
"-" => ((Func<int>)(() => {
    Log("subtraction");
    return a - b;
}))(),
"/" => ((Func<int>)(() => {
    Log("division");
    return a / b;
}))(),
_ => throw new NotSupportedException()
};
```

Just because switch expressions are new doesn't mean they are the best for all use cases. They are not designed to contain multiple commands.

Edit:  I suppose you could also simply call external functions instead of making anonymous ones.
[1]: https://alexatnet.com/cs8-switch-statement/

Comment: _"It's not designed to contain multiple commands."_ and is certainly not more readable.

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen that's the understatement of the year.

Comment: this is actually very similar to javascript event functions.  They are designed for a single call but you can embed a function in them.

Answer (score 6):

With:

```cs
TRes Call<TRes>(Func<TRes> f) => f();
```

its looks like:

```cs
return command switch {
  Command.C1 => new P1(),
  Command.C3 => new P2(),
  _ => Call(() => { stream.Position++; return null; }),
};
```

or:

```cs
var result = operation switch {
  "+" => Call(() => {
    Log("addition");
    return a + b;
  }),
  "-" => Call(() => {
    Log("subtraction");
    return a - b;
  }),
  "/" => Call(() => {
    Log("division");
    return a / b;
  }),
  _ => throw new NotSupportedException(),
};
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: it's also basically ripping off my answer