# Can I use a C# switch expression if there are actions that will appear inside the switch?

Tags: c#

Is there a way I can *clean* this code using a c# `switch` expression:

```
bool FileOperation(string _path)
{
    bool _newDb;

    if (File.Exists(_path))
    {
        _newDb = false;
        File.Delete(_path);
    }
    else
    {
        _newDb = true;
    }

    FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(
      _path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

    ReadWriteStream(
      Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open(sqliteFilename), writeStream);

    return _newDb;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to clean up I would rather assign the File.Exists to the _newDB variable directly instead of assigning it in the if else statement.

You can also rather use `FileMode.Create` instead of `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`, to always create a new file (and delete the old one if it exists).
[FileMode Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=netcore-3.1)

**Example:**

```cs
bool FileOperation(string _path) {
    // Setting _newDB bool equal to true if the file doesn't exist.
    bool _newDb = !File.Exists(_path);
    
    // Create new fileStream with using to dispose of it after we are done.
    using FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(
        _path, 
        FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
        FileAccess.Write);

    ReadWriteStream(
        Android.App.Application.Context.Assets
        .Open(sqliteFilename), writeStream);

    return _newDb;
}
```

You could use [switch expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890226/multiple-statements-in-a-switch-expression-c-sharp-8) if really wanted tough, but it's more of a workaround and definitely doesn't aid the visibility of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like the code below; I doubt if there's any need in `case` here:

```
bool FileOperation(string _path)
{
    // _newDb is true if and only if _path does not exist
    bool _newDb = !File.Exists(_path);

    // using: do not forget to dispose IDisposable (e.g. Stream)
    // FileMode.Create: create a new file or rewrite (i.e. delete and create new)
    using FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(
      _path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

    ReadWriteStream(
      Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open(sqliteFilename), writeStream);

    return _newDb; 
}
```